# How to get the index of an element in a singly linked list?

Tags: c#, indexing, stack, singly-linked-list

I have two classes:

SLList for methods (private SLElement _root)

SLElement for creating new elements for the list. (public int _value; public SLElement _next)

I have finished the add-method:

```
public void Add(int value)
{
  SLElement addNewElement = new SLElement();
  addNewElement._value = value;
  SLElement rootCopy = _root;
  _root = addNewElement;
  addNewElement._next = rootCopy;
  Console.WriteLine(addNewElement._value);
}
```

So now I want a remove-function. I already got it working that it removes an element with a specific value, but I want it so that it removes an element with an specific index. How can I find out the index of the elements in my list?

Comment: is this a homework? any reason you don't use c# linked list? you should skip i elements,and remove current element

Comment: What will happen when i call _next on SLElement which hasn't next element?

Comment: You get a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop throw index times and find the element

```
public SLElement Remove(int index)
{
    SLElement prev = _root;
    if(prev == null) return null; //or throw exception
    SLElement curr = _root.next;
    for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
    {
      if(curr == null) return null; //or throw exception
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr.next;
    }
    prev.next = curr.next; //set the previous's node point to current's next node
    curr.next = null;
    return curr;
}
```

Comment: this really helped me alot, thank you :)                              one more thing: I think you might want to change "return rtn;" to "return curr;" ?

Answer (score 4):

You need traverse your list from its head, counting along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a strong reason for which you would like to create your own, I believe you should go for a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

```
var list = new LinkedList<SLElement>();

list.AddAfter(list.AddFirst(new SLElement()), new SLElement());

list.Remove(list.Select((i, j) => new { i, j })
    .Where(j => j.j == 0)//remove the first node
    .Select(i => i.i)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: no its not a homework, i am 16 and just began my training and now I have to make a single linked list myself to understand how it works :)